# Angular 2 , find next few elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in my Angular 2 app. I need to get the next five elements in the array with a key greater than the one I passed.

```
If I pass key = 1, should return values with keys [2,3,4,5,6]
If I pass key = 2, should return values with keys  [3,4,5,6,7]
If I pass key = 10, should return values with keys  [11,12,13,14]
If I pass key = 12, should return values with keys  [13,14]

[
{key: "1", value: "value1"}
{key: "2", value: "value2"}
{key: "3", value: "value3"}
{key: "4", value: "value4"}
{key: "5", value: "value5"}
{key: "6", value: "value6"}
{key: "7", value: "value7"}
{key: "8", value: "value8"}
{key: "9", value: "value9"}
{key: "10", value: "value10"}
{key: "11", value: "value11"}
{key: "12", value: "value12"}
{key: "13", value: "value13"}
{key: "14", value: "value14"}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: possibly something like `let newArr = ogArr.filter(obj -> parseInt(obj.key)>key || parseInt(obj.key)<(key+scale));` where `key` is an integer parameter and `scale` is an integer that tells how many items to include in the new array

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [
{key: "1", value: "value1"},
{key: "2", value: "value2"},
{key: "3", value: "value3"},
{key: "4", value: "value4"},
{key: "5", value: "value5"},
{key: "6", value: "value6"},
{key: "7", value: "value7"},
{key: "8", value: "value8"},
{key: "9", value: "value9"},
{key: "10", value: "value10"},
{key: "11", value: "value11"},
{key: "12", value: "value12"},
{key: "13", value: "value13"},
{key: "14", value: "value14"}
]   

 getNextFive = (key) => { 
      const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.key == key); // no type checking
      if (index > -1) { // if key exists in data
         return data.slice(index + 1, index + 6).map(val => parseInt(val.key))
      } else {  // if key doesnt exist in data
         return []
      }
    }

console.log(getNextFive(1));
console.log(getNextFive(2));
console.log(getNextFive(10));
console.log(getNextFive(12));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArr = [];
data.forEach(function (eachObj) {
    if (eachObj.key > kaypassed && i <= 5) {
         newArray.push(eachObj.value);
         i++;
    }
});
console.log(newArray[]);
```

Comment: Where have you defined `newArray`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all objects with a key that is less than the provided key using JS `filter` and then `splice` if the returned array has more than 5 elements. See below.

```
getNextEls = (key) => {

  var arr = data.filter((x) => {
    return parseInt(x.key) > key
  })

  arr = arr.length > 5 ? arr.slice(0, 5) : arr
  return arr
}
```

Now if you want to return just the key or values of those, you can add the below conditional in the filter.

```
if (parseInt(x.key) > key){
  return parseInt(x.key) //if you want the key.
  return x[x.key] //if you want the values
}
```

```js
var data = [{
    key: "1",
    value: "value1"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    value: "value2"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    value: "value3"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    value: "value4"
  },
  {
    key: "5",
    value: "value5"
  },
  {
    key: "6",
    value: "value6"
  },
  {
    key: "7",
    value: "value7"
  },
  {
    key: "8",
    value: "value8"
  },
  {
    key: "9",
    value: "value9"
  },
  {
    key: "10",
    value: "value10"
  },
  {
    key: "11",
    value: "value11"
  },
  {
    key: "12",
    value: "value12"
  },
  {
    key: "13",
    value: "value13"
  },
  {
    key: "14",
    value: "value14"
  }
]

getNextEls = (key) => {

  var arr = data.filter((x) => {
    return parseInt(x.key) > key
  })
  
  arr = arr.length > 5 ? arr.slice(0, 5) : arr
  return arr
}

console.log(getNextEls(1))
console.log('-----')
console.log(getNextEls(2))
console.log('-----')
console.log(getNextEls(3))
console.log('-----')
console.log(getNextEls(12))
```